# Httpclient GetAsync Fails(503 Service Unavailable) inside Web API on IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, getasync

I have a simple web api that will retrieve a image file and return the bytes to the caller. It will work when I host the api project inside visualstudio in local (IIS Express), however, it will fail when I publish this project to my IIS server. Anyone has any idea?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("GetBytesCount")]
    public async Task<int> GetBytesCount()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0) };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(@"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var imageBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        return imageBytes.Length;
    }

}
```

if I called it from local box

```
http://localhost:57988/lkr/api/v1/Test/Getbytescount
```

it will return

```
int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1689</int>
```

When I call it from my server, it will return

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
......
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Comment: As an unrelated side note, you should use `response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`

Comment: Please do not delete the stacktrace...the stack trace points to a line number in your code....

Comment: @ Matias Cicero, I agree, I will chang the code.

Comment: Is there an entry in the EventLog on the server?

Comment: @Hackerman it is the line "response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();" throw the exception. The http status code is 503.

Comment: Can you tell us which version of the .net framework your project use?

Comment: HTTP 503 is *The Web server is effectively 'closed for repair'. It is still functioning minimally because it can at least respond with a 503 status code, but full service is impossible i.e. the Web site is simply unavailable. There are a myriad possible reasons for this, but generally it is because of some human intervention by the operators of the Web server machine. You can usually expect that someone is working on the problem, and normal service will resume as soon as possible.* - That points to a server problem - not anything in your code

Comment: Also can you tell us if your IIS machine match the .net framework?

Comment: @Hackerman my project's target framework is 4.5.

Comment: Did you have the 4.5 .Net Framework installed on your IIS machine?

Comment: @ Shannon Holsinger, you gave me a new idea to change a different url to give a try. Thanks

Comment: @Hackerman, yes the server has 4.5 installed.

Comment: @Rob Lang, unfortunately, I don't have the right to view the server log.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `Global.asax` `Application_Start()` method? I tend to find that 503 is given when the server is trying but cannot start your application.

Comment: @Rob Lang,I think my site is running fine. I can access other pages and apis without any problems. The exception is thrown when the httpclient is tying to call the thirdparty site.

Comment: Then I agree with @ShannonHolsinger, you will need to report a bug with the 3rd party.

Comment: @Rob Lang,  the server may have something to do with it, but one thing bothers me is why it works when running in local host mode. Something might relate my IIS server too.

Comment: @L.T. I agree that you might need to make a change in IIS but the error is being reported internally; all the 5xx HTTP status codes mean that it's a problem with their server, not yours.

Comment: looks like the server has some setup that the image site doesn't like. I switched my code to another server on the cloud, seems working fine. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Project Properties.

Get SSL URL and use in your browser to access the resource.

[image]